# How can we prevent code repetition without a JavaScript framework?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written some repetitive code to create 5 SVG circles inside a list. All five circles only differ between two attributes, the amount of left margin and the text next to the circle.

Like any good developer I would hope their is a way to create a sort of loop or something to reduce code duplication.

For example, If I have three circles such as

```
<!--                            NavBar                         -->
<div class="nav_bar_container">
    <ul id="nav_bar">

        <li style="margin-left: 15px;">
            <svg height="100" width="100">
                <circle id="Experience" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke-width="3" class="expand disabled"> </circle>
            </svg>
            <span>
                <b> One </b>
            </span>
        </li>


        <li style="margin-left: 0px;">
            <svg height="100" width="100">
                <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke-width="3" fill="#231f20"> </circle>
            </svg>
            <span>
                <b> Two </b>
            </span>
        </li>


        <li style="margin-left: 15px;">
            <svg height="100" width="100">
                <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke-width="3" fill="#231f20"> </circle>
            </svg>
            <span>
                <b> Three</b>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This occupies a lot of space, while only have minor differences within the text into the SVG's and the margins to the left.

Does anybody know a nice way to reduce code duplication?

Comment: you could create those list items with *javascript* - which is one of the tags you used for the question :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I am ok with using JavaScript, I just did not want to use something like React, Vue.js ect for a small scale website. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: since your ok with using javascript, how about you provide an example and then ask why your example doesn't work

Comment: Code duplication can be prevented by writing your code with the [DRY method](https://www.codementor.io/joshuaaroke/dry-code-vs-wet-code-89xjwv11w). It's a style of writing your code in a way that everything is reusable at any time. For example, when you're writing code and you notice you've written something before, put it in a function and call it whenever you need it. Create small functions that perform a single task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use js to reduce code duplication

```js
let settingArray = [
    {
    className: 'nav_bar__item',
     circleOptions: {cx: 50, cy: 50, r: 30, 'stroke-width': 3, fill: '#231f20'},
     spanOptions: { title: 'One' },
    },
    {
    className: 'nav_bar__item',
     circleOptions: {cx: 50, cy: 50, r: 30, 'stroke-width': 3, fill: '#231f20'},
     spanOptions: { title: 'Two' },
    },
    {
    className: 'nav_bar__item',
     circleOptions: {cx: 50, cy: 50, r: 30, 'stroke-width': 3, fill: '#231f20'},
     spanOptions: { title: 'Three' },
    }
  ];

let wrapper = document.querySelector('#nav_bar');
draw(wrapper, settingArray);

function draw(wrapper, settingArray){
  let items = [];
  
  settingArray.forEach(setting => {
    items.push(createItem(setting));
  });
  
  items.forEach(item => {
    wrapper.appendChild(item);
  })
}

function createItem(setting){
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.className = setting.className;
  
  li.appendChild(createCircle(setting.circleOptions));
  li.appendChild(createSpan(setting.spanOptions));
  
  return li;
}

function createCircle(options){
  let svg = createSVG('svg', { height: 100, width: 100});
  
  let circle = createSVG('circle', options);

  svg.appendChild(circle);
  
  return svg;
}

function createSVG(tag, attrs) {
    const elem = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
    for (let attr in attrs) {
      elem.setAttribute(attr, attrs[attr]);
    }
    return elem;
}

function createSpan(options){
   let span = document.createElement('span');
   
   let b = document.createElement('b');
   b.textContent = options.title;
   
   span.appendChild(b);
   
   return span;
}
```

```css
.nav_bar{}
.nav_bar__item:first-child{
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.nav_bar__item:last-child{
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.nav_bar__item{
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_bar_container">
    <ul id="nav_bar">    
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow that's a lot more code than I originally anticipated. I will give it a go.

Comment: If my answer helped solve the problem, then mark it as correct